# Rails - set a db field to null from another object's controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to set a Cabinet's Device's attributes to null in a disconnect method.  cabinets_controller calls `@cabinet.devices.destroy(@device)` and that works ok.  Before I do that I want to set `@device.row_id = nil` and `@device.position = nil`.  They are both Fixnum and attr_accesible in the Device model.  They are not being altered in the DB when I call this method.  Is there a method to call on `@device` to make this happen?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Are you trying to update a record right before you destroy it?

Comment: The destroy method only removes the association.  In this instance it removes cabinet_id from the device record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're trying to break the connection between a @cabinet and a @device without completely deleting the @device. If you're already sure that @device belongs to @cabinet, it might be more straightforward to do something like:

```
@device.row_id = nil
@device.position = nil
@device.cabinet_id = nil
@device.save!
```

Basically you'll need to call .save or .save! on @device after setting those other fields to nil; while you're at it you may as well set cabinet_id that way, too.

Comment: Ah yes! I am such a fool.  Thanks @sockmonk.